# put space and pattern automatically after 6 characters in input javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I want to automatically put a "pattern" and a space after 6 digits in my input field and I want the user can continue to write after the pattern.
whenever pattern would be match, a space will be added in input field.

Now I am getting a space from my code but did not get pattern. please help. Thanks in advance.

let's say.......

let pattern = xxx-x~xx;

input = 123456789123456789123456789

input field should be --> 123-4~56 789-1~23 456-7~89 123-4~56 789

```
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
   let val = e.target.value;
   setInputVal(spacify(val));
  };

function spacify(str, after, c) {
if (!str) {
    return false;
}
after = after || 4;
c = c || " ";
var v = str.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
    reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g");
return v.replace(reg, function (a) {
    return a + c;
}).replace(/[^0-9]+$/, ""); }



return(
  <div>
   <input
      type="text"
      value={inputVal}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  </div>
);
```